# Foreign Key contraints MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to insert into two tables here, one is creating a document which goes into my doc_list table and the other takes the ID's from checkboxes and posts them into a join table.

The issue being that the join table expects an id form the post I am creating but I simply cannot provide it one so I am getting the error.

The problem is here: `$docId = $dbh->lastInsertId();`

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`dashboardr`.`cat_doc_link_table`, CONSTRAINT `cat_doc_link_table_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`link_doc_id`) REFERENCES `doc_list` (`doc_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

If I change it to: `$docId = $_POST["doc_id"];`

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'link_doc_id' cannot be null

Here is the form I am posting out from:

```
<?php include 'header.php'; ?>
<?php 

require_once '../../db_con.php'; 

try{
    // Selecting entire row from cat_list table
    $results = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM cat_list");

}catch(Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
}

$category = $results->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

?>


<h3 class="subTitle">
    <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></span> Create New Document
</h3>

<form action="actions/newDocAdd.php" method="post" id="rtf" name="">

    <input type="text" name="doc_title" id="doc_title" required="required" placeholder="Document Title"/><br />

    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="doc_id"/>

<label><input type="checkbox" name="" class="selectall"/> Select all</label>

<div id="checkboxlist">
    <?php
        foreach($category as $cat){ 
    ?>

    <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $cat["cat_id"]; ?>" name="cat_no[]"><?php echo $cat["cat_title"]; ?></a>
    <br>

    <?php
    }
    ?>
</div> 

    <textarea name="doc_content" id="doc_content" placeholder="Document Content" style="display: none;"></textarea>
    <iframe name="editor" id="editor" style="width:100%; height: 600px;"></iframe>

    <br><br> 
    <input onclick="formsubmit()" type="submit" value="Create Document" name="submit"/>


</form>
```

Here is the script which actions the form:

```
    /*******************************************************************
    **  ACTION SCRIPT TO POST A NEW CATEGORY INTO THE DOC_LIST TABLE  **
    *******************************************************************/


    if(isset($_POST["action"])){
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    include_once'../../config.php';

    try {

    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=dashboardr",$username,$password);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO doc_list (doc_title, doc_content, doc_created, user_id) 
            VALUES ('".$_POST["doc_title"]."','".$_POST["doc_content"]."',NOW(), '".$_SESSION['user']."')";

    $SQL = "INSERT INTO `cat_doc_link_table`(`link_cat_id`, `link_doc_id`) VALUES";
    $values = "";
    $params = [];
    $docId = $dbh->lastInsertId();

    foreach($_POST["cat_no"] as $cat)
    {
        $values.= "(?, ?), ";
        $params[] = $cat["cat_id"];
        $params[] = $docId;
    }
    $values = substr($values, 0, -2);
    $SQL.= $values;
    $query = $dbh->prepare($SQL);
    $query->execute($params);       

    if ($dbh->query($sql)) {

        header ('Location: ../docList.php?success=1');
    }else{
    }

    $dbh = null;
        }catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

    }

    }


    ?>
```

I am fairly new to relational tables so please be gentle as I am really trying to understand the fault and how to rectify this issue as I am extremely close to resolving the problem.

Comment: Please post the contents of the variable `$SQL` so we can see what the final string is, and also `print_r($params)`.  You also have `$sql` which is different, and vulnerable to SQL injection without placeholders. That statement could easily fail, but it looks like you called `lastInsertId()` before calling `$dbh->query($sql)` -- which is what executes the first insert and therefore produces the insert id.

Comment: My apolgies for the mixed up code - So could you post a snippet as to where I should be calling in `lastInsertId()` if you wouldn't mind?

Comment: I'll see if I can piece it together. I would like to see `print_r($_POST['cat_no'])` though.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski her eis a result of me printing `$sql`  =  `INSERT INTO doc_list (doc_title, doc_content, doc_created, user_id) VALUES ('dsfdg','dfgfd',NOW(), '10')`

Comment: `$sql` is easy enough to understand, but please post the other one, `$SQL`. That's a multi-insert and has more complex string operations.

Comment: If I try posting out what you suggested I get a blank page

Comment: Blank page? A parse error because of a missing `;` on `print_r($_POST['cat_no']);`

Comment: Array ( [0] => 4 ) SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`dashboardr`.`cat_doc_link_table`, CONSTRAINT `cat_doc_link_table_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`link_doc_id`) REFERENCES `doc_list` (`doc_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

Comment: does that help at all?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78126/discussion-between-phpcoder-and-michael-berkowski).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out:

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=dashboardr",$username,$password);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$insertDocList = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO doc_list (doc_title, doc_content, doc_created, user_id) 
    VALUES (:docTitle, :docContent, NOW(), :user)");

if( $insertDocList === false ) {
    die("statement couldn't be prepared");
}

$insertResult = $insertDocList->execute(array( 
    'docTitle'      => $_POST['doc_title'],
    'docContent'    => $_POST['doc_content'],
    'user'          => $_SESSION['user']
));

if( $insertResult === false ) {
    die("Insert Failed");
}

$docId  = $dbh->lastInsertId();

$SQL = "INSERT INTO `cat_doc_link_table`(`link_cat_id`, `link_doc_id`) VALUES";
$values = "";
$params = [];
//...
```

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1065 Query was empty

Comment: @phpcoder, ideally, you would use a debugger...but in the absence of that, you can use `die()`.  Try the above, and let me know what statement gets executed.

Comment: Ok, so get this SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1065 Query was empty

Comment: @phpcoder, comment out your setAttribute to throw exceptions to let the die() statements execute if applicable.

Comment: If you don't get either of the die() statements, then your problem would be with the bottom query...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78128/discussion-between-phpcoder-and-kevin-nelson).

Answer (score 1):

You need to execute the first `INSERT`, before you try to use `$dbh->lastInsertId`.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO doc_list (doc_title, doc_content, doc_created, user_id)
                VALUES (:doc_title, :doc_content, NOW(), :user_id)";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array(':doc_title' => $_POST["doc_title"],
                     ':doc_content' => $_POST["doc_content"],
                     ':user_id' => $_SESSION["user"]));
$docId = $dbh->lastInsertId;
```

This code should be before the `foreach` loop in your code. And you should get rid of the call to `$dbh->query($sql)`.

Comment: It looks like you have changed my variables? Could you show an example using my code?

Comment: I get this error SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''6', NULL)' at line 1

Comment: I don't see where that's coming from, there's no `NULL` in my query.

Comment: How could I find out?

Comment: You got rid of `$dbh->query($sql)`, right? This code executes that query, you shouldn't do it again.